# vista complete PC restore complains my new drive is too small, but the destination is bigger than the source partition

Tags: windows-vista, windows-backup

Tryng to do a Vista complete PC restore from an image made of a 450GB system partition C:. 
This C: partition is inside a 2TB HDD with the following partition setup

[Hidden DELL 78MB partition][D:DELL_RECOVERY 2GB][C:OS 450GB][unallocated 1348GB]

I made said image using Vista complete PC backup whilst ensuring to only include drive letter C: (the complete PC backup utiliy gives you the option to include/exclude available drives, drives C: and D: were available and I excluded drive D).

As I try to restore this image into a 550GB HDD the restore complains the destination drive isn't large enough. It must be getting confused, perhaps evaluating 2TB->550GB, but I only want 450GB->550GB

Any ideas as to how I could make this work?

Any insights as to how Vista PC backup and restore works that can explain the behaviour I am seeing?

Thanks

### Edit : 4 April 2013 16:04

I just restored from an earlier backup I had when the system was running off a 270GB drive into the 550GB drive. This worked (I've never had a problem from smaller to larger HDD), but I now noticed that the restore seems to include the 78MB DELL hidden partition which I never specified I wanted to backup nor restore. (nor am I given the option to incude or ignore)

So it seems that the Windows full PC backup/restore is including stuff that is out of user control. Anyone know what it does exactly?

Comment: Despite your claims you only selected the system disk the image appears to contain the unallocated space.

Comment: Interestingly, when I don't exclude the D drive the backup content lists drive C and D. When I do exclude it the backup only lists drive C. So what I am doing is at least having that effect. Nevertheless, from your coment do I read that you have succeeded in doing this sort of thing yourself and hence that it is possible using Vista complete PC backup/restore? How would I go about ensuring the backup doesn't contain the unallocated space?

Comment: Yes I have used Vista complete PC to restore an image to another hdd before.  I would just use a different tool in a case like this one that was so limited.

Comment: I meant going from a smaller partition in a larger drive to a larger partition in a smaller drive which is the whole point of this post